# Time difference in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to print start & end time of stage in pipeline along with time taken for completing stage. Not getting expected result.

```
script{def start_time = new Date()
echo "Start Date: ${start_time}"                
sleep time: 2, unit: 'MINUTES'
def end_time = new Date()
def total_time = end_time - start_time
echo "End Date: ${end_time}"
echo "Total Time: ${total_time}"}
```

Comment: What are you getting, and what do you expect?

Comment: I dont see any value for total_time

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting dates in groovy will give you the duration in *days* - most
likely your jobs are not running that long.

Instead use e.g. `System.currentTimeSeconds()` to calculate the duration in
seconds.

Comment: Should I not consider start and end time for a stage ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeDuration` and `TimeCategory` :

```
import groovy.time.* // I don't remember whether Jenkins pipelines do this differently

//your stuff

TimeDuration duration = TimeCategory.minus(end_time, start_time)

echo "Total Time: ${duration}"
//something like "Total Time: 2.063 seconds"
```

Printing `duration` will give you a human-readable representation. You can also do `duration.toMilliseconds()` if you need a numeric value for calculations, metrics, etc.